# 2Dcostmaps are not working properly

Tags: slam, costmap-2d, local-costmap

I DON'T use a pre-built map and i am trying to do navigation. I am using gmapping for that.

1. First of all the rolling window in local costmap is not working at all.
2. Second problem is that it doesn't detect dynamic obstacles.

For those who thought right away that the problem is that i am using static_layer in a local_costmap, i have to tell you that if i remove it then the image 4 is happening (same happens to global_costmap if i remove static layer)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I solved the problem of rolling window by putting the parameters in common_costmap_params.yaml file . But i cant solve the problem of static map . Actually the first time i placed the parameters in  this file i executed the program and it worked for good, detecting dynamic obstacles etc. but then i restarted the program and it wasn't working anymore